# Instantiating GameObject in edit mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some graph of `Node` objects, which help represent some internal game state. I want to be able to spawn `GameObjects` from a prefab, initializing associated `Node` objects, using the GUI - i.e. someone could extend `nodes` in the example below in edit mode.

I am not familiar with how to do this in edit mode, instead of instantiating at runtime.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I get further than the below? I am familiar-ish with `ScriptableObject`  but am not sure if it is relevant/necessary here.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class UGraph : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject nprefab;
    [SerializeField] List<Node> nodes;

    public void CreateNode(Transform transform)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(nprefab, transform.position,
                                    transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        AddToGraph(go.GetComponent<Node>());
    }

    public void AddToGraph(Node node)
    {
        node.Graph = this;
        nodes.Add(node);
    }
    ...
```

Some thoughts around this taken from: https://gist.github.com/Problematic/a14aeb0638a09f378ad3

Comment: See [CustomEditors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) for design-time stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Lece - this is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lece pointed me towards the following page one extending the editor: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html

This helped me discover how to use `EditorWindow`, and activate `Instantiate` via button press.

```
public class NodeCreator : EditorWindow
{
    ....

    [MenuItem ("Window/Node Creator")]
    static void ShowWindow()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(NodeCreator));
    }

    ....

    void OnGUI()
    {
        ....
            if (GUILayout.Button("Create"))
            {
                tempobj = Instantiate(obj) as GameObject;
                ...
            }
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ContextMenu("PutANameHere")]` Can do this thing in edit mode & play mode.

Here is an example of spawning White and black prefabs on scene to make a checkered floor. To call the function in edit mode just right click  [Snapshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pt4z.png) the object that implements the method:

[image]

> public GameObject whiteTile, blackTile;
>
> ```
> public float tileSize = 0.25f;
> public float floorSize = 5f;
>
> [ContextMenu("PutANameHere")]
> public void Generateobjects()
> {
>     int rowElements = Mathf.CeilToInt(floorSize / tileSize);
>     for (int i = 0; i < rowElements; i++)
>     {
>         for (int j = 0; j < rowElements; j++)
>         {
>             GameObject spawnPrefab;
>             if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
>                 spawnPrefab = whiteTile;
>             else
>             {
>                   spawnPrefab = blackTile;
>             }
>
>             Vector3 nextPositon = new Vector3(transform.position.x + i * tileSize, transform.position.y,
>                 transform.position.z + j * tileSize);
>             var spawned = Instantiate(spawnPrefab);
>             spawned.transform.position = nextPositon;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```